# What is the difference between expected value and 'most likely' value?

Tags: probability

Consider the below question:

On Halloween trick-or-treaters arrive at a house from 5:30pm until 9pm according to a Poisson Process with an average of 12 trick-or-treaters per hour.

(a) How many trick-or-treaters would be expected to arrive over the whole evening?
(b) What number of trick-or-treaters is most likely to arrive?

The first part of the question is quite straightforward and is equal to the value of lambda(rate)=42.

But how do we do the second part? what is the difference between expected value and 'most likely' value?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The expected value might be a value that will not appear at all. The most likely value is the value that will appear the largest number of times.

Comment: The expected value for the number of legs a person has is slightly below 2. The most likely value is 2.

Comment: The expected value is the mean; the weighted average value.  The most likely value is the mode; the most probable value.

Comment: @Regret: Nice example, but you should strive to make it clearer. In short, Most people around the world have $2$ legs. Very few are unfortunate to have only $1$ leg, or even $0$ legs due to various circumstances (birth defects, car accidents, mass war crimes by ISIS, etc). So the expected (average) number of legs per person is slightly below $2$. However, since the vast majority of people still have $2$ proper legs, the most likely number of legs that a person has is $2$.

Comment: If the mean $\lambda$ of a Poisson distribution is not an integer then the mode is at the next smaller integer. If $\lambda$ is an integer there is a "double mode" at $\lambda$ and $\lambda -1.$ This can be deduced by looking at the ratio of the PMFs, r(i) = p(i)/p(i-1).

Comment: any suggestions what the appropriate **notation** would be for the *most likely*, as opposed to the *expectation value* ($\mathbb{E}(\eta)=\cdots$)? I can't think of a good way. Is there some convention?